# Variables Variable (Creating variable with the name of another variable)

Tags: javascript

i want to create a new variable with a variable name,
for example:

```
function preloader(imglist) {

  var imgs = imglist.split("|");

    for (i in imgs) {

      var img_{i} = new Image;  //this is the line where i sucked in!
      img_{i}.src = imgs[i];    //another line where i sucked in!

    }
}

preloader("asd.jpg|qwe.jpg|dorama.png");
```

i try to use arrays but, hmm.. how can i say...

```
var qwe = new Array();
qwe[1] = "asd"; //or not! whatever...

var qwe[1] = new Image; // it didnt work!
```

in php u can use like this:

```
$var1 = "test";
$var2_{$var1} = "test last";
echo $var2_test; //or...
echo $var2_{$var1};
```

Comment: Why do you want an unique name on the variable? In your example I see no reason at all to user "dynamic variable names". Just use plain "var img = new Image();"

Comment: Yes, you don't need unique names - when you say `img = new Image()`, it doesn't overwrite the old img value.  You don't need this PHP weirdness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that here, each `Image` can be stored and overwritten to get the same preload effect, however just this will work:

```
function preloader(imglist) {
  var imgs = imglist.split("|");
  for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
    new Image().src = imgs[i];
  }
}
```

Note that I changed this from a `for in` loop, you should use a normal index `for` loop when iterating over an array (not enumerating) [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) has [a great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848) explaining this in more detail.

Comment: Well, it will work, but the `img` variable's scope is the function, not the `for` loop.

Comment: @Tim - good point, updated though since it's not even needed their either unless you intended to use it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but why for loop? i mean when i use like this:  var imgs = Array(); imgs[1] = "asd"; imgs[2] = "qwe"; /*and then*/ var i; for(i in imgs) { document.write(imgs[i] + "<br />"); } // is working...

Comment: @dreamlore - Click the great answer link for a lengthy explanation on this, basically you should never use a `for in` to iterate an array, as it's *enumerating* the object (and any *other* properties it may have) not *iterating* it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mojavelinux.com/articles/javascript_hashes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achive your goal by using `Eval()` function as shown below;

```
var data = "testVariable";
eval("var temp_" + data + "= new Array();");
temp_testVariable[temp_testVariable.length]="Hello World";
alert("Array Length: " + temp_testVariable.length);
alert("Array Data: " + temp_testVariable[0]);
```

Of course it doesn't mean that is the right solution. I have just given the information about the ability.

Here is the [article](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/dynamic-variables-in-javascript) that contains the above sample and an alternative solution using `Window` object.